# Teamcity - CI/CD - iOS - xcodebuild - signing - No signing certificate "iOS Development" found

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, teamcity, xcodebuild

I have Teamcity installed with an Agent on a MAC. When I try to build the iOS project I have this error:

```
error: No signing certificate "iOS Development" found: No "iOS Development" signing certificate matching team ID "#######" with a private key was found. (in target 'App' from project 'App').
```

**I use this command line:**

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace ios/App/App.xcworkspace -scheme App clean build
```

I did test the command in a terminal directly on the mac and it Works! My certificates are located in the keychain in the session of the user that runs the Agent of Teamcity.

I did try to put the certificate in another keychain and grant access to the process that is executed by Teamcity using this command :

```
security unlock-keychain -p [password] ~/Library/Keychains/teamcity.keychain-db
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this. The issue was that for some reason teamcity was looking at System keychain, and of course found nothing.
Adding certificate to the system keychain resolved this.